# d3: tooltips on multi series line chart at each line when mouse hover event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, typescript

I am drawing charts with d3 in my Angular 2 application. Now I have a multi series line chart so I am trying to add tool tips at each line when hover its' vertical position.

```
export class LineGraphDirective {
  private host;
  private svg;
  private margin;
  private width;
  private height;
  private xScale; // D3 scale in X
  private yScale; // D3 scale in Y
  private zScale; // D3 color scale
  private xAxis;
  private yAxis;
  private line;
  private htmlElement:HTMLElement;
  private parseDate;
  private ds;

  constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
    this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.host = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
    this.parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
    let data = [];
    this.ngOnChanges(data);
  }

  /**
   * Every time the @Input is updated, rebuild the chart
   **/
  ngOnChanges(data):void {
    this.setup(data);
    this.initData(data);
    this.buildSVG();
    this.scaleAxis(data);
    this.populate();
    this.drawXAxis();
    this.drawYAxis();
    this.zoomEventHandler();
    this.addVerticalLineTooltip();
  }

  private setup(data):void {}

  private initData(data) {}

  /**
   *  build  SVG element using the configurations
   **/
  private buildSVG():void {}

  private scaleAxis(data) {}


  /**
   * Create x axis
   **/
  private drawXAxis():void {}

  /**
   *create y axis
   **/
  private drawYAxis():void {}

  /**
   * Populate the graphs
   **/
  private populate():void {}

  private addVerticalLineTooltip() {
    // append a g for all the mouse over nonsense
    let mouseG = this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    // this is the vertical line
    mouseG.append("path")
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    // keep a reference to all our lines
    let lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    // here's a g for each circle and text on the line
    let mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(this.ds)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    // the circle
    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", (d) => {
        return this.zScale(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    // the text
    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    // rect to capture mouse movements
    mouseG.append('svg:rect')
      .attr('width', this.width)
      .attr('height', this.height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', () => { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', () => { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', () => { // mouse moving over canvas
        let mouse = d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget);
        console.log(lines);

        // move the vertical line
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", () => {
            let d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + this.height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        // position the circle and text
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
            console.log(i);
            let beginning = 0,
              end = d3.select(lines[i]).node().getTotalLength(),
              target,
              pos;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = d3.select(lines[i]).node().getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }
            console.log(this.yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            // update the text with y value
            d3.select(this).select('text') // **Error this.querySelector is not a function
              .text(this.yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            // return position
            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Now it shows vertical line with circles at each line but it doesn't show the values (tooltips). Following error is displaying on console log.

```
this.querySelector is not a function

console.log(this.yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));
```

Above console log prints Y-axis values correctly on mouse hover event.

Any suggestions.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have created tooltips on multi series line chart as per your requirement it's working good.

You need to make some changes into your code to set position of tooltips from bellow example links

See Example Here

[Multi Series Line Chart with Tooltip](http://bl.ocks.org/ChandrakantThakkarDigiCorp/e9d02fd497d433c59c5780ed2593fd09)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
      .attr("transform", (d, i, f) => {
        console.log(i);
        let beginning = 0,
          end = d3.select(lines[i]).node().getTotalLength(),
          target,
          pos;

        while (true) {
          target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
          pos = d3.select(lines[i]).node().getPointAtLength(target);
          if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
            break;
          }
          if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
          else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
          else break; //position found
        }
        console.log(this.yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

        // update the text with y value
        d3.select(f[i]).select('text') // **Error this.querySelector is not a function
          .text(this.yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

        // return position
        return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
      });
```

Comment: adding a bit of detail concerning the error in the OP and then suggesting the code would be nicer