# d3: Chart zooming doesn't effect to the tool tips

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm added zoom ability to a multi series line chart I've built with d3 and Angular 2. Also the chart has a capability of displaying vertical line with tool tips at each line at their vertical position (I followed [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fk6gfwjr/1/)). Here is my code below.

```
export class LineGraphDirective {
  private host;
  private svg;
  private margin;
  private width;
  private height;
  private xScale; // D3 scale in X
  private yScale; // D3 scale in Y
  private zScale; // D3 color scale
  private xAxis;
  private yAxis;
  private line;
  private htmlElement:HTMLElement;
  private parseDate;
  private ds;
  private make_x_axis;
  private make_y_axis;

  constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
    this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.host = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
    this.parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

    let data = [];

    this.ngOnChanges(data);

  }

  /**
   * Every time the @Input is updated, rebuild the chart
   **/
  ngOnChanges(data):void {
    this.setup(data);
    this.initData(data);
    this.buildSVG();
    this.scaleAxis(data);
    this.populate();
    this.drawXAxis();
    this.drawYAxis();
    this.zoomEventHandler();
    this.addVerticalLineTooltip();
  }

  private setup(data):void {
    this.margin = {top: 50, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100};
    this.width = 600;
    this.height = 400;
    this.xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]);
    this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
    this.zScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    this.zScale.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) {
      return key !== 'date';
    }));
  }

  private initData(data) {}

  /**
   *  build  SVG element using the configurations
   **/
  private buildSVG():void {
    this.host.html('');

    this.svg = this.host.append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
      .attr('height', this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

    this.svg.append('clipPath')
      .attr('id', 'clip')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', this.width)
      .attr('height', this.height);
  }

  private scaleAxis(data) {}


  /**
   * Create x axis
   **/
  private drawXAxis():void {}

  /**
   *create y axis
   **/
  private drawYAxis():void {}

  /**
   * Populate the graphs
   **/
  private populate():void {}

 /*Add tooltip at each line when hover its vertical position*/
  private addVerticalLineTooltip() {
      // append a g for all the mouse over nonsense
    let mouseG = this.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    // this is the vertical line
    mouseG.append("path")
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    // here's a g for each circle and text on the line
    let mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(this.ds)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    // the circle
    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", (d) => {
        return this.zScale(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    // the text
    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    // rect to capture mouse movements
    mouseG.append('svg:rect')
      .attr('width', this.width)
      .attr('height', this.height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', () => { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', () => { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', () => { // mouse moving over canvas
        let mouse = d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget);
        let lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line'); // keep a reference to all our lines

        // move the vertical line
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", () => {
            let d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + this.height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        // position the circle and text
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
            let beginning = 0,
              end = d3.select(lines[i]).node().getTotalLength(),
              target,
              pos;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = d3.select(lines[i]).node().getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            // update the text with y value
            d3.select(d3.event.currentTarget).select('text')
              .text(this.yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            // return position
            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  }

  private zoomEventHandler() {

    let zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 10])
      .translateExtent([[0, -100], this.width + 90, this.height + 100]).on("zoom", () => this.zoomed());

    this.svg.call(zoom);
    d3.select('button').on('click', ()=>this.resetted(zoom));
  }

  private zoomed() {

    d3.select('.x-axis').call(this.xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(this.xScale)));
    d3.select('.y-axis').call(this.yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(this.yScale)));
    d3.selectAll('.line').attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');
    d3.selectAll('.circle').attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');

  }
}
```

Now the chart can be zoomed on mouse wheel & can be dragged. But the vertical line with tool tips remaining as before, it doesn't match with the zoomed lines of the chart. Following screen shot is for your kind reference.

[image]

d3 version is 4.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you !

Comment: You zoomed function applies it to the axis and things with a class of `.line` and `.circle`.  You need to apply it to the tooltip elements as well:  `d3.select('.mouse-over-effects').attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');`

Comment: Thanks Mark. Its' working. Hope u can help me to find the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438578/d3-tooltips-on-multi-series-line-chart-at-each-line-when-mouse-hover-event